# Anchor Offset not working on Here Maps Map Overlay (iOS Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, here-api

I have an iOS app written in Swift on which I'm implementing Here Maps (Premium). I have placed markers and I have implemented the method to display an Info Window popup when a user clicks on the marker. I implemented it by initiating a UIViewController and adding it as a subview to a NMAMapOverlay. I then add the NMAMapOverlay to the NMAMapView.

The Info Window/Overlay displays perfectly, but the problem is that it displays centered directly over the marker as is the default behaviour as mentioned [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAMapOverlay.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMAMapOverlay(py)anchorOffset). I want to position my overlay slightly higher up on the screen so that the info window's bottom edge coincides roughly with the top of the marker. According to the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAMapOverlay.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMAMapOverlay(py)anchorOffset) I should be able to set anchorOffset to position the overlay relative to the anchor/coordinates. However, setting the anchorOffset has no effect. Am I using it incorrectly? Am I missing something? How do I position my Overlay so that it appears at the top of the marker rather than centered over it?

For reference I am showing the code below that I'm using to add the Overlay:

```
let infoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomInfoWindow", owner: self, options: nil)!.first! as! CustomInfoWindowController
let coords:NMAGeoCoordinates = NMAGeoCoordinates(latitude: marker.coordinates.latitude, longitude: marker.coordinates.longitude)
let overlay: NMAMapOverlay = NMAMapOverlay()
overlay.coordinates = coords
overlay.addSubview(infoWindow)
overlay.isHidden = false
overlay.anchorOffset = CGPoint(x:0, y:-50) //This has no effect. Why not?
mapView.add(mapOverlay: overlay)
```

Comment: We are unable to reproduce the issue. Everything works as expected. We tested it on the current master and 3.12 release.
Which version of the SDK are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As HERE Support has already mentioned,
"We are unable to reproduce the issue. Everything works as expected. We tested it on the current master and 3.12 release. Which version of the SDK are you using?"
We need the above info.

Comment: We are using 3.5.0.

Comment: Upgrading to the latest version that has since been released solves the problem.